# The Arctic Plate

Tags: environment, climate, geography, geology

In this alternate Earth, each ocean has its own plate, and the Arctic is no exception.

[image]

Horizontally cutting Iceland in half, we can find the border three to seven miles off the coasts of Labrador, Baffin Island, Alaska, Russia and Norway, creating chains of volcanoes that include the Scandes.  Note that the Polar Atrial Ridge diverges east and west, pushing the outer boundaries of the plate to squeeze beneath the Northern Plate (North America, Russia, Central Asia, Europe). The result — volcanic mountain chains varying in height above sea level from 15,776.7 to 19,341 feet.  In the ocean itself, the ratio between average depth and maximum depth is still the same, though the number is now deeper--average, 1652 meters.

The alternate map above is not 100% accurate.

The Atlantic is 1350 miles wider than ours.  Africa, Eurasia and Australia have, compared to our Old World, moved that far eastward, creating a landbridge that connects Asia to North America, erasing the Bering Strait off the map and shrinking the Bering Sea. To that extent, it would be like turning the Russian urban locality of Egvekinot (66.3205 degrees North and 179.1184 degrees West) into the next-door neighbor of Teller, Alaska.

Also, the island of Greenland is rearranged to the extent that Mont Forel, the island’s highest peak, is located in 90 degrees North — the North Geographic Pole.

These changes would obviously have dramatic consequences on the global climate, but would these changes be enough so that in the event of a climate crisis with a timeline identical to our own, the extent of the summer melt won't be so severe, pronounced?

Comment: You have two "too broad" and one "unclear" close votes. Maybe try to explain how you got oceans on such plates? It seems you created some impossible geology and without knowing how, people may be unable to help you.

Comment: It's 2 + 2 now, one vote from putting on hold. Consider some rewriting.

Comment: Adding another map to show the original plate boundaries and explicitly saying 'I want to change this picture to this picture, what would that mean' might make this clearer.

Comment: Changed the question.

Comment: "have dramatic consequences" - how dramatic they are and why - you can point us in some direction, as I do not see how it have to be dramatic - Antarctica have continent and we are pretty cool with that.

Comment: @MolbOrg  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JohnWDailey - yes, exactly, that is why I posted the comment

Comment: @MolbOrg  No, it was your comment that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JohnWDailey yes, I know what you have meant, but you didn't gave me any clue how I can improve it in a way it would make sense to you. I think we have usual situation when two not native do not get each other - I'm right?

Comment: "two not native"?

Comment: How on Earth is this "unclear"?